# Printing a (part of) webpage with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, printing

I am aware of two ways of calling the "print" dialog of browser (I used the Search, of course):

- document.print()
- document.execCommand('print', false, null)

What is the difference between them? Support across browsers? Papers, docs or standards? Which is more correct thing to use?

Another question: what is the most straight way to print given part of a webpage? I know we can create new window or iframe to call any of two print methods above. Which one has less pitfalls?

Comment: In most cases, you would use document.print(). Check out the documentation for document.execCommand here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand

Comment: @HarveyA.Ramer that link does not document any `print` command.

Comment: @torazaburo Here's a great round-up of printing possibilities from GitHub that does include execCommand('print') examples: https://gist.github.com/Rast1234/8598949  It looks like that uses this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've tested different ways of printing part of webpage across browsers:
Chrome, Firefox, Opera (12 and new), IE11, 10, 9 and 8. I've tried to create new `window`, new `iframe`, or use `existing iframe` on the page. And then tried `.print()` and `.execCommand('print')`.

*Note: Keep in mind that .print() is called on **window**, and .execCommand() is called on **document***.

Code used for testing can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Rast1234/8598949)

Correct me if my testing code is wrong, I just wanted to find the clearest way to do the job. My conclusions:

- Opera 12 can not print part of a webpage (?)
- IEs don't `print()` iframes and windows, except current window.
- Calling `print()` on `documents` inside iframes or created windows in IEs breaks the `print()` on current `document`. Be careful!
- jQuery plugin [printThis](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis/) uses tricks for IE to do the job, and it just works. The only exception is Opera 12. By the way, this plugin uses `print()`.
- `execCommand('print')` works almost everywhere and with any approach (iframes, window). It's not supported by Firefox though.
- `execCommand()` returns `false` if call was unsuccessful, so if you don't want to use plugins and magic tricks, create window or iframe, call `execCommand('print')` and if it returns `false`, call `print()`.

One more thing:

Creating an `iframe` is tricky: you can't access its **window** or **document** directly (yes, you have ContentDocument property, which behaves differently across browsers). You should **name** it and then call `window.frames[name]` to get **window** object from that iframe. Do not try to call `window.frames(id)` - it will return the **iframe**.

Comment: On an Android browser, `window[iframeName].document.execCommand('print')` seems to print the entire page. Have you seen that?

Comment: Note that according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=document-execcommand, this is not supported on Android 5-6 (Lollipop-Marshmallow).

Comment: @torazaburo No, my interest was only of desktop broswers.

Comment: @torazaburo I'm getting the same issue. Android chrome prints the entire page and not just the iframe. Did you get any workaround this? Appreciate if anybody can help.

Comment: @Rajkishore This is a known bug which is still outstanding, unfortunately I'm too lazy to track down the link at the moment.

Comment: +1, this is the most elaborate answer I can find on SO so far. I ended up using execCommand('print') method because I'm trying to print part of an iframe. Also I'm unable to get a hold of window object inside the iframe. I'm not sure about the reason why its not accessible, probably because parent frame uses srcdoc in combination with sandbox to render iframe or may be due to something else. The only thing concerning is I'm supposed to add support for tablet as well, so might have to look into the issue mentioned above by @user663031.

Answer (score 4):

That last method mentioned in the accepted answer, then, ends up looking like this:

```
iframe = document.getElementById('iframe-id');
var printed = iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);

if (!printed) window.print();
```

alternative:

```
try {
    iframe = document.getElementById('iframe-id');
    iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
}
catch(e) {
    window.print();
}
```

similar method used by printThis

```
if (document.queryCommandSupported("print")) {
    $iframe[0].contentWindow.print();
    $iframe[0].contentWindow.document.execCommand("print", false, null);
} else {
    $iframe[0].contentWindow.focus();
    $iframe[0].contentWindow.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of window.open and execComand (saveas
exemple:

```
<script  type= "text/javascript">
 function saveas() {
  var oPrntWin = window.open("","_blank","width=1,height=1,left=1,top=1,menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,resizable=yes,location=no,scrollbars=yes");
  oPrntWin.document.open();
  oPrntWin.document.write(editeur.innerHTML);
  oPrntWin .document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"C:\\My Documents\\Saved Content.html");
 oPrntWin.document.close();
 }
 </script>
```

**editeur.html is a part of my document** 
 you can do same for your frame 
replace the writting in a new Window by the property "src" for the body

Comment: this question is about sending a page to printer, not about saving it as a file